# Referenced from Linker error if -ObjC flag is added in other linker flag settings iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Am working on iOS app with GooglePlus.framework. When I build the app it crashes with the below log,

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM gtm_httpArgumentsString]:
```

What I did was, I just add -ObjC in other linker flag settings to solve the above crash. But it throws some linker errors like below,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSignInManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AWSFacebookSignIn(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.o)

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(UIDevice+GPPAdditions.o)

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(NSData+GPPAdditions.o)
```

Is there any way to fix this linker error, ***since -ObjC is essential for google plus authentication***. Can anyone help me on this to figure out. Also, let me know if there is any possibility or procedure to make it work ***(Google Plus) without -ObjC option***.

Comment: `CLLocationManager` and `ALAssetsLibrary` are symbols from CoreLocation framework and AssetsLibrary frameworks. Do you have these two linked to your app's target via "Link Binary with Libraries"? `AWSSignInManager` symbol should also be in some framework that you have to link.

Comment: Great it works fine when I added the missing frameworks in  "Link Binary with Libraries". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the missing frameworks in the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section in XCode.